# aspx intellisense not working. Tag Recommendation become <%@ %>. How to solve this?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, tags, devexpress

I don't know what happens after i left my laptop for one week.
My text editor does not show the `html` tag and other tag, just showing tags like in below.
How can i get tag recommendation or intellisense back ? Thanks.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having searched through the DevExpress support tickets, I assume that this is a problem in the newest VS 2019 (16.10) update:

[T1003000 - IntelliSense works incorrectly in Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.10.0](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t1003000)